# Pivot a table and combine result with aggregate of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with columns: Sales_Margin: Branch,   Item Code, Item Name, Sale Qty, Sale Rate, Cost, Margin

Catalogue:
VERTICAL, ITEM ID, PARTS DESCRIPTION

I need output in such a way that the distinct values in VERTICAL from Catalogue table are columns and Branches from Sales Report table are rows. 
I got that part using pivot:

My Code:

```
select branch as Branch, [Vertical1], [Vertical2], [Vertical3], 
[Vertical4]
from 
( 
select branch, vertical, round((sum(margin)/sum([Sale Rate])),3) [Avg GM]
from
Sales_Margin JOIN Catalogue
ON Sales_Margin.[Item Code] = Catalogue.[ITEM ID]
group by branch, VERTICAL
) x
pivot
(
    sum([Avg GM]) 
        for vertical 
    in([Vertical1], [Vertical2], [Vertical3], [Vertical4])
) as pivot_table
```

But I also need sum of 'Margin' column from Sales Report table such that Margins are grouped by the Branch (Will copy output to excel and take Percentages)
Expected Output:

```
  Branch Vertical1 Vertical2 Vertical3  Vertical4       Margin
       A1       0%       9%       52%         0%       A1 Margin
       A2       40%      9%       66%         1%       A2 Margin    
       A3       32%      4%       57%         2%       A3 Margin    
       A4       17%      9%       65%         17%      A4 Margin
```

I tried using a correlated subquery as below but it doesn't work:

```
select branch as Branch, [Vertical1], [Vertical2], [Vertical3], 
[Vertical4], 
(select sum(Margin) from Sales_Margin a where a.Branch = 
x.branch)
from 
(
select branch as Branch, [Vertical1], [Vertical2], [Vertical3], 
[Vertical4]
from 
( 
select branch, vertical, round((sum(margin)/sum([Sale Rate])),3) [Avg GM]
from
Sales_Margin JOIN Catalogue
ON Sales_Margin.[Item Code] = Catalogue.[ITEM ID]
group by branch, VERTICAL
) x
pivot
(
    sum([Avg GM]) 
    for vertical 
    in([Vertical1], [Vertical2], [Vertical3], [Vertical4])
) as pivot_table
) z
```

It says,

```
The multi-part identifier "x.branch" could not be bound.
```

could someone please let me know how to get the Margin column with numeric values added grouped by branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `z.branch`, as it is referencing that outer subquery.